# SoftLayer API result and actual billing period

Tags: ibm-cloud-infrastructure

In my SoftLayer account, it looks like my billing period starts on 1st of each month.  When I make some API calls to get my account's last invoice and its billing item data, I get a result like this:

```
   "account" : {
      "id" : 930277,
      "latestBillDate" : "2016-05-01T00:00:00-05:00",
      "latestRecurringInvoice" : {
         "amount" : "0",
         "closedDate" : null,
         "createDate" : "2016-05-01T00:36:56-05:00",
         "id" : 8363665,
         "invoiceTopLevelItems" : [
            {
               "billingItem" : {
                  "cancellationDate" : null,
                  "createDate" : "2016-03-10T16:18:23-06:00",
                  "currentHourlyCharge" : "10.472",
                  "cycleStartDate" : "2016-05-01T00:36:56-05:00",
```

And I am wondering about the invoice createDate and billingItem cycleStartDate.  They seem to have same date and time.

So, if the invoice was created at 2016-05-01T00:36:56-05:00, does this mean
that in this bill the hourly usage charge includes up to a second before 2016-05-01T00:36:56-05:00? And next bill will charge starting from this time?

Or is it that even if the bill was generated about 36 minutes after the beginning of 2016-05-01, the bill only covers the hourly usage up to end of 2016-04-30? and that the next bill will cover the charge from the 1st second of 2016-05-01 to last second of 2016-05-31?

Anybody knows?
It is about billing and how much to charge and not.
So I need an accurate answer.
Thank you.

Comment: See below for the answer and comments, but to summarize the answer to this and related question, the cycleStartDate does not tell the beginning of recurring billing period.  It's that date with 00:00:00 time with whatever the timezone difference it has which is the actual charge starting time for this period.

And for the first bill, to find out when the charge started, use the "createDate" property of the billingItem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think better you open a ticket in softlayer and ask to the sales guy about the charge.

Comment: This may be slightly different from my original question, but still very related...  So the SoftLayer support tells me that hourly order start to get charged when the order is approved (either manual or automatically).  I am using API to get SoftLayer_Billing_Item detail.  Which one of these attributes tells me this date and time where the hourly billing starts (and monthly prorated billing starts) on the first bill?  Is it the "createDate" value?

Comment: you can see when the biilling starts, by looking the "createDate" property of the billingItem, the charge must start from that date.

Comment: Thank you for confirming that.